# Cannot resize and save image of type .tif after patch extraction with tf

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to build a patch-wise image classifier network, therefore I want to extract patches from a .tif image and then save them as file:

```
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

file = 'data/test/Benign/b001.tif'
patch_path = 'data/patches/'
k = 1495  # window size
s = 99  # stride


def extract_patches(img_file, img_name):
    img = cv2.imread(img_file)
    padd = tf.constant([[29, 29, ], [21, 20], [0, 0]])
    img = tf.pad(img, padd, "CONSTANT")
    img = tf.expand_dims(img, 0)
    c = img.get_shape()[-1]  # color

    extracted = tf.extract_image_patches(
        images=img,
        ksizes=[1, k, k, 1],
        strides=[1, s, s, 1],
        rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
        padding='VALID')

    patches_shape = extracted.shape
    patches = tf.reshape(extracted, [tf.reduce_prod(patches_shape[0:3]), k, k, int(c)])
    patch_num = patches.shape[0]

    for i in range(patch_num):
        sess = tf.Session()

        curr_patch = patches[i]
        print(type(curr_patch))
        print(curr_patch.shape)

        # decode_patch = tf.image.decode_image(curr_patch, channels=3)
        # print(type(decode_patch))
        # print(decode_patch.shape)

        resized_patch = tf.image.resize_images(curr_patch, [299, 299], method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR)
        print(type(resized_patch))
        print(resized_patch.shape)

        encode_patch = tf.image.encode_jpeg(resized_patch)
        print(type(encode_patch))
        print(encode_patch.shape)

        fwrite = tf.write_file(patch_path + img_name + '/' + str(i) + '_' + img_name, encode_patch)
        sess.run(fwrite)


extract_patches(file, 'test.tif')
```

This is the output that I get currently:

> class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'
>
> (1495, 1495, 3)
>
> class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'
>
> (299, 299, 3)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Mary\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 510, in _apply_op_helper preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Mary\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 1104, in internal_convert_to_tensor
>       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Mary\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 947, in _TensorTensorConversionFunction
>       (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
>
> ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype uint8 for Tensor with
>   dtype
>
> float32: 'Tensor("resize_images/Squeeze:0", shape=(299, 299, 3),
>   dtype=float32)'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):    File
>   "C:/Users/Mary/PycharmProjects/FineTune_18_12_10/patchbazi.py", line
>   51, in 
>       extract_patches(file, 'test.tif')
>
> File "C:/Users/Mary/PycharmProjects/FineTune_18_12_10/patchbazi.py",
>   line 43, in extract_patches
>       encode_patch = tf.image.encode_jpeg(resized_patch)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Mary\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_image_ops.py",
>   line 1439, in encode_jpeg
>       name=name)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Mary\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 533, in _apply_op_helper
>       (prefix, dtypes.as_dtype(input_arg.type).name))
>
> TypeError: Input 'image' of 'EncodeJpeg' Op has type float32 that does
>   not match expected type of uint8.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

as you can see, when I try to **encode_jpeg(resized_patch)**, I get the type mismatch error. Without the **tf.image.resize_images()**, everything works perfectly, so I guess there is some type change happening in the resize function.  I also tried decoding the image as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42193508/3764197), but apparently the decoder works only for few file extensions. Can some one help me with it?

I am using python 3.6.5 and tensorflow 1.12.0

Comment: What is the shape of `img` after the line `img = tf.reshape(img, (1, img.shape[0], img.shape[1], img.shape[2]))`?

Comment: @GPhilo it's (1, 1594, 2089, 3), basically just adding one dimension to the image.

Comment: Yeah, rereading the line I saw that. I suggest you use [`expand_dims`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) for that instead, it's much more clear (and possibly more efficient too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs of [`tf.image.resize_images`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_images) (emphasis mine):

> The return value has the same type as images if method is
>   ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR. It will also have the same type as
>   images if the size of images can be statically determined to be the
>   same as size, because images is returned in this case. **Otherwise, the
>   return value has type float32**.

You need to cast the result to `uint8` which is the expected type for the input of `EncodeJpeg`:

```
encode_patch = tf.image.encode_jpeg(tf.cast(resized_patch, tf.uint8))
```

Also, as a side note, `type(my_tensor)` is not useful to know what type is the *data* in the tensor. Either print `my_tensor` directly, or `my_tensor.dtype`.